# How to analyze the data from the packet (like pcap or cap)is the inflow or outflow of the host?

Tags: network-programming, wireshark, pcap, packet-capture

I have a packet like pcap or cap, how to analyze the data from the packet is the inflow or outflow of the host? I use Python and Scapy.

Comment: How do you have it? is it pcap format? is it text file?

Comment: I have it use wireshark, then save as pcap format

Comment: Read one of the responses here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207423/code-to-analyze-pcap-file , it provides some Python code

Comment: thank you， I just right use Python and Scapy,too!

Comment: Before jumping into programming, it would help to understand what you mean by inflow or outflow of the hosts.  Do you mean the packets sent by a host and packets received by a host?   What analysis do you want to do on the packets? Do you want to match the inflow packets against a pattern?

Comment: yes，I mean the packets sent by a host and packets received by a host, thanks, I have solved this problem.